# android callback interface in Websocket onMessage

Tags: java, android, websocket

**I am trying to create library for websocket send.**

```
public class SocketCls {
    private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;
    private void connectWebSocket(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
        URI uri;
        uri = new URI(url);

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                final String message = s;
              // Here i want to use callback
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }
}
```

**Normally i can achieve it but when i want it to put in separate package how to use callback ? please can anyone help me out this**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some interface WebSocketListener,
which will contain onMessage, onClose, onError, etc.

and in constructor of your SocketCls you can set this listener and use it in websockets callback

```
public class SocketCls {
public interface SocketListener  {
    void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake);
    void onMessage(String s);
    void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b);

}

SocketListener listener;

public SocketCls(SocketListener l) {
    listener = l;
}
private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;
private void connectWebSocket(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri;
    uri = new URI(url);

    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
            mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
            listener.onOpen(serverHandshake);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String s) {
            final String message = s;
            // Here i want to use callback
            listener.onMessage(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            listener.onClose(i, s, b);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    };
    mWebSocketClient.connect();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please explain me how to call connectWebSocket method in another package with listener.. please

Comment: if you want to call connectWebSocket, you should make it public